# Design Pattern for Ajax throbber before initial data has been fetched in backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My application has couple of backbone models and collection. I want to place an ajax throbber before all models/collections have been synced from the server.

Can someone direct me to or explain me any design pattern they might have used to place the ajax throbber before all models/collections have been synced rather then rendering the views before the data has been synced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fetch()` method returns a jQuery promise. You can therefore do something like the following in your app:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fetchA, fetchB, modelA, modelB, viewA, vieB;
    startThrobber();
    modelA = new ModelA();
    modelB = new ModelB();
    fetchA = modelA.fetch();
    fetchB = modelB.fetch();
    $.when(fetchA, fetchB).then(function () {
        stopThrobber();
        viewA = new ViewA({model: modelA});
        viewB = new ViewB({model: modelB});
        viewA.render();
        viewB.render();
        ....
    });
});
```